# Is this pagination or something else?

Tags: php, pagination, mysqli

I'm still learning more interesting details about PHP. Example: Moving from MySQL to MySQLi. What I am currently doing is trying enter something like this: http://music.daum.net/artist/main?artist_id=2289

From what I learned from pagination by dicing the url:

- main?
- artist_id=
- 2289

How can I be able to make a page like that? I have 2 sections available and will make the others when figuring this out.

- artist information (available as *testhub-artist.php*)
- album (available as *testhub-artistalbum.php*)
- music video
- photo section

I want to make it easier when making pages instead of making separate folders for each person.

My url would be: "../artist/detail?artist_id=#"

---

This is at the top of the artist page.

```
<?php
//Connect to ...
include "testhub-artist.php";
include "testhub-artistalbum.php";
?>
```

testhub-artist.php

```
<?php
//Connect to database
include "mysqli_connect.php";

// Construct our join query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM individuals WHERE soloID = 1";

// Create results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

// Checking if query is successful
if($result){

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

// If else states on each variable
    if ($profilepic = $row['profilepic']){
        $profilepic = $row['profilepic'];
    }else{
        $profilepic = "DamjuNoImage";
    }
    if ($engname = $row['engname']){
        $engname = $row['engname'];
    }else{
        $engname = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($korname = $row['korname']){
        $korname = $row['korname'];
    }else{
        $korname = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($engbn = $row['engbn']){
        $engbn = $row['engbn'];
    }else{
        $engbn = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($korbn = $row['korbn']){
        $korbn = $row['korbn'];
    }else{
        $korbn = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($dateofbirth = $row['dateofbirth']){
        $dateofbirth = $row['dateofbirth'];
    }else{
        $dateofbirth = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($occupation = $row['occupation']){
        $occupation = $row['occupation'];
    }else{
        $occupation = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($debut = $row['debut']){
        $debut = $row['debut'];
    }else{
        $debut = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($recordlabel = $row['recordlabel']){
        $recordlabel = $row['recordlabel'];
    }else{
        $recordlabel = "Unknown";
    }
    if ($officialsite = $row['officialsite']){
        $officialsite = $row['officialsite'];
    }else{
        $officialsite = "#";
    }
    if ($sitename = $row['sitename']){
        $sitename = $row['sitename'];
    }else{
        $sitename = "Unknown";
    }
} // End of while statement
}else{
    $engname = "Unknown";
    $korname = "Unknown";
    $engbn = "Unknown";
    $korbn = "Unknown";
    $dateofbirth = "Unknown";
    $occupation = "Unknown";
    $debut = "Unknown";
    $recordlabel = "Unknown";
    $officialsite = "#";
    $sitename = "Unknown";
} // End of If statement

// Free result set
//mysqli_free_result($result);

?>
```

testhub-artistalbum.php

```
<?php
//connect to db
include "mysqli_connect.php";

//check for a page number. If not, set it to page 1
if (!(isset($_GET['albumpage']))){
    $albumpage = 1;
}else{
    $albumpage = $_GET['albumpage'];
}

//query for record count to setup pagination
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE soloID = 3";
$album_data = mysqli_query($link, $sqli);
$album_rows = mysqli_num_rows($album_data); 

//number of photos per page
$album_pagerows = 4; 

//get the last page number
$last_album = ceil($album_rows/$album_pagerows); 

//make sure the page number isn't below one, or more than last page num
if ($albumpage < 1){
    $albumpage = 1;
}elseif ($albumpage > $last_album){
    $albumpage = $last_album;
}

//Set the range to display in query
$max_album = 'limit ' .($albumpage - 1) * $album_pagerows .',' .$album_pagerows;

//get all of the photos
$albumList = "";
$sqli2 = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE soloID = 3 ORDER BY releasedate DESC $max_album";
$album_sql = mysqli_query($link, $sqli2);

//check for photos
$albumCount = mysqli_num_rows($album_sql);

if ($albumCount > 0){
    while($album_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($album_sql)){
    $albumID = $album_rows["albumID"];
    $albumpic = $album_rows["albumpic"];
    $title = $album_rows["albumTitle"];
    $releasedate = $album_rows["releasedate"];
    $page = $album_rows["page"];
    $albumList .= '
      <li class="albumthumb">
         <a href="' . $page . '" title="' . $title . '"><img class="profile" src="../albums/album_th/' . $albumpic . '.jpg" alt="' . $albumpic . '" width="120" height="120" border="0" /><p class="datatitle">' . $title . '</p></a><p class="data-releasedate">' . $releasedate . '</p>
       </li>
                  ';
    }
}else{
    $albumList = "There are no available albums at this time!";
}

//mysql_close();
?>
```

Sorry for not explaining clearly. I want to be able to use pagination when making a profile page like the url. I want to use the number in the url to change the id (soloID) in the sql code.

Good idea in saving time, right? MySQLi getting easier every time I see it.

Thank you.

---

Changed 5/31/2012 5:44PM CT

```
$artist = $_GET['artist_id']
```

into

```
    if(is_numeric($_GET['artist_id'])){
    $artist = $_GET['artist_id'];
}else{
    $artist = 1;
}
```

Comment: -1 Because it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot to add at the bottom.

Comment: `if ($profilepic = $row['profilepic']) {$profilepic = $row['profilepic'];}`? Ouch. Magic numbers, not using parameters even when employing a library that supports it. This code needs a lot of work.

Comment: I should just change it to '$profilepic = $row['profilepic'];' instead of that?

Comment: You're using an assignment operator rather than a comparison. Also the true branch is redudant.

Comment: I'm still new so I don't fully understand. I mostly understand how to make variables.

Comment: I am reading this now: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
artist/detail?artist_id=#
```

You would use `detail` as the page, (probably have a detail folder with a index) and on the detail page, have a `$_GET[]` variable somewhere that gets the artist_id. So your code could look something like this:

```
$artist = $_GET['artist_id']; // Filter this variable

$sql = "SELECT * FROM individuals WHERE soloID = '{$artist}'";

/**
 * Verify if the ID exists
 * Display query results, etc.
 */
```

So everytime you change the artist_id variable in the URL, the page should change accordingly.

Comment: It worked. So what about mysqli_real_escape_string? I read about sql injections.

Comment: That should be fine for preventing SQL injections, but if the artist_id is going to be an integer I would check if the value is an integer without any kind of weird characters.

Comment: Alright. I'll go look that up since I'm sure if it be a if statement or something.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to my second favorite language!  I love php.
Someone already answered your question, but I have some suggestions.

The code you have isn't vulnerable as is cause the user provided data is passed through math... but inlining variables is a good way to leave yourself open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.   Look up [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and prepared statements and get in the habit of using them.  Always.  Well almost always..

Unfortunately SQL doesn't allow you to bind things like the values you use for `LIMIT,ORDER BY,GROUP BY` so you have to handle those yourself.
Never trust anything derived from a user, so do the work and check it.

Sort columns should always be column names.  Check them.

```
if ( ! in_array($sort_column,array('column1','column2','column3') ) ) $sort_column = 'column1';
```

Limits should always be integers.  Cast them as such.

```
$safe_limit = (int) $user_limit;
```

There is no need to copy the array values into another variable.  Just use them directly.

You need to escape your values going into html.  Lookup [urlencode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [htmlentities()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

My IE is up to a gig of memory so I'll have to finish this up later.